# How to pass options to meteor cordova pluginst install? Installing phonegap-plugin-push

Tags: cordova, meteor

During meteor build: `meteor build --directory ..\outputdir --server myserver.tk:3232`

I've got error because plugin phonegap-plugin-push@1.7.2 requires **--variable SENDER_ID=value** when installing it in simple cordova project like this **cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="XXXXXXX"**:

```
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:

   While adding plugin phonegap-plugin-push@1.7.2 to Cordova project:
   Cordova error: Variable(s) missing (use: --variable SENDER_ID=value).
   (If the error message contains suggestions for a fix, note that this
   may not apply to the Meteor integration. You can try running again with
   the --verbose option to help diagnose the issue.)
```

How to escape such error in Meteor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read about [mobile-config](http://docs.meteor.com/api/mobile-config.html)

Then You need to include in Your mobile config:

```
App.configurePlugin('phonegap-plugin-push', {
  SENDER_ID: 'xxx'
});
```

Comment: It's helped. Thanks a lot!